# Pandas Data Frame Select column last value and replace with blank

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with lots of columns, I wanted to replace the last value of few of columns with blank, what is the best way to do that.

the thing is data frame can be dynamic with values and length.

Here is the data frame:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2BI2.png)

How can I remove values from **column F** and **G** to blank?

please except typos as I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.index[-1], ['G', 'F']] = np.nan
```